# Items visible in a ListView inside a Grid in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, grid, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an Universal App using Xamarin Forms.

The code is only on the Universal project and I'm creating the graphics adding the components via code and passing them to the ContentPage.

The page contains a Grid with the size of the screen. Inside the grid there are two ListViews, each one using vertically half of the screen.

To retrieve the visible items I'm using the two events ItemAppearing and ItemDisappearing. I need to know not only the visible elements but also the top one.

The issue is that in Android the system loads four items in the first ListView to fit the space then activate the scrollbar to scroll to the others. The same code in Windows loads more elements also if only four are visible, and debugging I found that is loading more elements to fit the full screen and not only the half where the ListView is.

Is the different behavior a bug in Xamarin? Are there other ways to retrieve the items visible and the top one?

I need something that works for all kind of devices not a partial solution.

```
public class Verses : ContentPage
{
    ListView listView, listView1;
    List<VERS> versesENG, versesOTH;

    public List<int> visible = new List<int>();

    public Verses(CHAPTER chapterENG, CHAPTER chapterOTH)
    {
        versesENG = chapterENG.VERS.ToList();
        versesOTH = chapterOTH.VERS.ToList();

        listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemsSource = versesENG;
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
        listView.HasUnevenRows = true;
        listView.RowHeight = -1;
        listView.ItemTapped += ListView_ItemTapped;
        listView.ItemAppearing += ListView_ItemAppearing;
        listView.ItemDisappearing += ListView_ItemDisappearing;

        listView1 = new ListView();
        listView1.ItemsSource = versesOTH;
        listView1.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
        listView1.HasUnevenRows = true;
        listView1.RowHeight = -1;
        listView1.ItemTapped += ListView1_ItemTapped;

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.Children.Add(listView, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BoxView() { HeightRequest = 1, BackgroundColor = Color.Accent }, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(listView1, 0, 2);

        Content = grid;
    }

    private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        VERS v = (VERS)e.Item;
        listView1.ScrollTo(listView1.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().ElementAt(v.vnumber - 1), ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);
        listView1.SelectedItem = listView1.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().ElementAt(v.vnumber - 1);
    }

    private void ListView_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        VERS v = (VERS)e.Item;

        visible.Add(v.vnumber);
        visible.Sort();

        var top = visible.First();

        this.Title = "L";
        visible.Count();
        foreach (int i in visible)
        {
          this.Title += " " + i.ToString();
        }
      }
    }

    private void ListView_ItemDisappearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        VERS v = (VERS)e.Item;
        visible.Remove(v.vnumber);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Its the potluck we lovingly call Android. Different versions of android handle controls differently. Things layout differently. Even if you find a solution that looks exactly like you want it too on a certain resolution on a certain device I can almost guarantee it wont look that way on the next device.

Its hard to give a good suggestion on how to "fix" this without screen shots or code. but for the most part with Vertical layout I'd say put them in a stack and let them have as much or as little room as they want. Small Devices will scroll big devices will have a huge empty block at the bottum.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've added some code, my app will allow to read contents in 2 languages, it's not important the graphics but the contents. I'd  like to synchronize the scrolling and selection between the two ListViews. For this reason i need to know the top Item and the visible ones.

Comment: Havent tried to do that myself but I recently needed to sync a list of dates with a calander control. We ended up using a CarouselView. Id think you could acomplish this with 2 carosel views and likely would have a little better control over the layout